# Why can't I use the http-server globally with node/RPM?

Tags: node.js, npm

I installed `http-server` globally but it does not show up in `"C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm\"` and I get the error

```
sh: http-server: command not found
```

I used following command

```
npm install -g http-server
```

Comment: Hi there!  What program/version are you using for a shell environment?  Cygwin?  Git Bash?  Something else?  Version numbers for Windows, node, http server might also be helpful.

Comment: Also, please show us the output of `npm install -g --verbose http-server`

Comment: the installation all goes well. I tried to install from cmd and git bash too. my git version is 1.9.4 and i am on windows 7.

Comment: I think its being installed in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\local\node_modules". so how can i fix it?

Comment: The verbose install log would still help.  Make sure that global node_modules directory you just quoted is on the lookup path for executables.  What does `echo $PATH` show?

Comment: when i add "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\local" to my PATH is working now. How can I default it to "C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\npm\"?

Comment: Google "add to path permanently bash".  Your .bashrc file is your friend.

Comment: thanxs @kdbanman for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\local" to PATH and it is working now.